# how to Order a CollectionA using ListB ordering it in order of ListB Items in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have 
Dim persons as List(of Persons) with fields like Name , City 
there is a list of City 
Dim City As New List(Of String)(New String() {"kolkata", "Delhi", "Chennai"})

Now I want to Order the persons list in Order of City .
i.e simply if a City is kolkata for the Person .
so list of persons should show kolkata at first place Delhi at second place and Chennai.

How can i Achieve this in vb.net

eg. 
      Dim abc = from m in persons 
                join n in City 
                on m.City equals n
                order by n (index)
                select m

Answer (score 1):

This has fairly horrific efficiency:

```
persons.OrderBy(Function(p) city.IndexOf(p.City) )
```

If you have a lot of people and/or cities it might be best to turn the city list into a dictionary first:

```
Dim cityD = city _
  .Select(Function(s, i) New With { Key .city = s, .index = i }) _
  .ToDictionary(Function(x) x.city, Function(x) x.index)
persons.OrderBy(Function(p) cityD(p.City) )
```

I think that's the syntax.. can't easily check at the mo.. will update when I'm on a computer

It basically builds a dictionary with the city name as the key and the list index as the value. It's a lot faster to lookup this way. It is mandatory that your city list have no duplicate city names! Duplicate is case sensitive so "Kolkata" <> "kolkata"

Comment: `_` is redundant ;)

Comment: @Fabio Yes, I thought that (for LINQ stuff at least), but [.net fiddle complained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXHz9.jpg) when I left it out (.net 472 chosen) so I put it in.. Leave your comment up as a pointer for other people that they can perhaps take it out! :)

Comment: Thanks caius . it was helpful and solved my problem .

Comment: @user3472553 Please accept the answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer so other user will be helped. It will also earn you a couple of reps.

Comment: @user3472553 if an answer is useful, click the up arrow  above the number. If an answer is the one you chose to use, click the gray ☑️ to turn it green ✅. Sometimes you'll get multiple answers; any number of answers can be up voted , only one can be accepted as the one you chose. Questions that have accepted answers show differently on the dashboard so people know they have been answered

Comment: @Fabio At least as recently as VS 2017, the `_` is still required in this context.

Comment: @Craig, `_` is redundant for `Method(). ` continuation on the next line - which is considered as "implicit line continuation" regardless of VS version. But I noticed only now that OP using c# way to chain method call with dot on next line. In vb.net if you leave dot on previous line you don't need underscore for continue chain on next line.

Comment: @Fabio handy to know, thanks! Since what VB version is it a feature?

Comment: @Fabio Thanks, I wasn't aware of the distinction.  I follow the same style as in the answer with the '.' on the next line as I think it's more readable for context.  (Although I'm fluent in C#, I didn't knowingly take it from C#.)